# angularjs checkbox and it aumatically checked when page load but can't be unchecked on a first try

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my uncheck box code:

I'm using JavaScript `onpageload` for getting my checkbox checked when the page loads.

```
function checkBox()
{
    test = document.getElementsByTagName("md-checkbox");

    for (i=0;i<test.length;i++)
    {
        if(test[i].getAttribute("aria-checked")=="false")
        {
            test[i].setAttribute("aria-checked","true");
            test[i].setAttribute("class","ng-valid md-default-theme md-checked ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched");
        }
    }
}
```

But now when I try to uncheck it, it is only unchecked on the second click.
So what can I do to fix that?

Comment: my uncheck box code:                                                                                                         <md-checkbox name="isLuxury" value="isLuxury" ng-model="isLuxury" role="checkbox" class="ng-valid md-default-theme ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched " tabindex="0" aria-checked="false" aria-invalid="false" aria-label="Luxury Buses Only. Like Volvo, mercedes etc.">

Comment: What is aria-checked? You can use ng-checked="false" or ng-checked="true"

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your html you can use two type of expression for checkbox;

**ng-modal**

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isCheckBoxTrue">
```

**ng-checked**

```
<input id="checkSlave" type="checkbox" ng-checked="false" aria-label="Slave input">
```

For your example;

```
function checkBox() {
   test = document.getElementsByTagName("md-checkbox");
   for (i=0;i<test.length;i++)
   {
       if(test[i].getAttribute("ng-checked")=="false")
       {
           test[i].setAttribute("ng-checked","true");
           test[i].setAttribute("class","ng-valid md-default-theme md-checked ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched");
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: @user3573919 if it is usefull can you apply my answer?

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and we can help you.